# Can't run subprocess on AWS EC2

Tags: php, python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We have an ec2 instance running with django rest framework. Now, there I want to be able to run a crontab that initiates a python script that calls a php script.

**test.py**

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        p = subprocess.Popen(['php', "/opt/python/current/app/my-app/my_test_file.php", name, caption], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        result = p.communicate()[0]
```

Now on my local machine I get no errors whatsoever. It works fine. And as you can see I use an absolute path there.

When uploading to ec2 and running I get this error:

> ```
> >       File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
> >         return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
> >       File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
> >         errread, errwrite)
> >       File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
> >         raise child_exception
> >     OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
> ```

What does this have to do with?
Is it because of a php file that it can't find? Because I also used this method as well:

```
directory = os.getcwd()
p = subprocess.Popen(['php', directory + "/my_test_file.php", name, caption], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

And that worked locally but again on ec2 gave that same error!

Please help! Thank You in advance!

Comment: You should give the full path to the php executable, and you may need to install php.

Comment: I did try using a full path: "/opt/python/current/app/my-app/my_test_file.php" but that did not work as well. I used readlink -f file.php to figure out the full path

Comment: I mean the full path to the php binary that executes your php code. E.g. `p = subprocess.Popen(['/path/to/php', "/opt/python/current/app/my-app/my_test_file.php"...`